# How to get special character string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the following string in C#. I would let to get each variable string starts with special chars "@" and replace with the stored proc string.

This is a test..

@Header_HTML

@BodyHTML

So, I would like to get each variable string "@Header_HTML", and @BodyHTML.

Call the stored proc passing these variable string.

Comment: Which part is not working? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: You're making your life harder than it needs to be by concatenating strings into a sql statement. Why are you not using commands and parameters instead?

Comment: Why the vb.net tag if you're askng about c#?

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex :

```
Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"\@[a-zA-Z_]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(sourceString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ItemMatch);
        }
```